# The role of super in OOP in JS

Tags: javascript, oop

I was learning OOP in JS and came across super() which is used to invoke the constructor of parent class. The question is Why do we need to call the constructor of parent class? Just why do we care?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Why do you make contructors, if you don't then use them?

Answer (score 3):

The constructor does **stuff**. What that stuff is depends on what the class is.

If you are creating a subclass then, most of the time, you will want to do the **same stuff**. Possibly with some extra things too.

Rather than copy/pasting the constructor function from the parent class and then editing it (which would require that you manually keep both functions in sync with each other if either changed) we use `super()` to call it instead.

Comment: Just as an example for this, say we have `class Employee extends Person` - the `Person` constructor will initialize anything needed for `Person` and you *want* that to happen. You don't need to repeat the logic for `Person` be a use if you make any changes to that class, you also have to change the children. The `Employee` constructor then *only* cares about anything `Employee` related.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `super` kind of maintains the connection between parent & child classes. When it's used like `super.myParentMethod()` it just calls `myParentMethod` declared in direct parent class or upper the road.

When it is called in the `constructor` of a child, it will call parent's `constructor`, so, the parent will be initialized before child is.

To fully understand why it's needed, you probably need to learn more about classes & constructor functions in JS.

There's an [extremely good article](https://javascript.info/class-inheritance) about this topic.